# Sahi not able to load images during automation using Java

Tags: automation, sahi

Images are not getting loaded during automation using Sahi and Java code. When the screen is opened through automation, the images are shown as "x" symbol and due to this, when I click on 'save' nothing happens but the screen closes. Whereas when I try to do this manually, after stopping the Sahi server, the images can be seen properly and also be saved. Is there any solution for this? The application under test runs in IE7.

Comment: any reproduction steps?

Answer (score 2):

These images may be from an external source or are delivered via Https. 
Check where the images come from and add this site to you Sahi SSLManager.
Then check your block_ssl_domains.txt and exclude_inject.txt, you may be blcoking ressources from this site.

Regards
Wormi